# Opening SFTP channel with JSch on chrooted-system fails with "failed to send channel request", but WinSCP works

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch, chroot

Running a SSHD with following setting for SFTP connection:

```
Match User service
  ForeCommand internal-sftp
  ChrootDirectory /media
  X11Forwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Now, conneting to sshd using JSch and connecting an "sftp" channel, I'll get following Exception:

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request

Here is my Java code (quite similar like form JSch website)

```
Session sshSession = JSSH.getSession(<USER>, <HOST>, 22);
sshSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
sshSession.setConfig("HashKnownHosts", "no");
sshSession.setPassword(<PASSWORD>);
sshSession.connect(5000);

Channel channel = sshSession.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect(); // <-- here exception is raised
ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
channelSftp.put(...);
```

If I disable `ChrootDirectory`-line in sshd configuration, everything works fine. But I am not able to change this line later in production (there it is present).

But with WinSCP, I can connect successfully to the same SFTP server even with `ChrootDirectory` on:

```
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 WinSCP Version 5.11 (Build 7715) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Enterprise)
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Log level: Normal
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Local account: MichaelLindner
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\SDE\WinSCP
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Process ID: 668
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\SDE\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Time zone: Current: GMT+1, Standard: GMT+1 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit), DST: GMT+2 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit), DST Start: 25.03.2018, DST End: 28.10.2018
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Login time: Freitag, 9. März 2018 15:46:23
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Session name: service@world (dev) (Modified site)
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Host name: world.local (Port: 22)
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 User name: service (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Tunnel: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Transfer Protocol: SFTP
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Disable Nagle: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Proxy: None
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Send buffer: 262144
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Bypass authentication: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 GSSAPI: Forwarding: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Simple channel: Yes
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Shell: /bin/bash
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 SFTP Server: default
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: No, Cache: Yes
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 DST mode: Unix
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.745 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-03-09 15:46:23.776 Looking up host "world.local" for SSH connection
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.795 Connecting to 192.168.0.1 port 22
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.795 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.11
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.904 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.904 We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.904 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.904 Have a known host key of type rsa2
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.920 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. 2018-03-09 15:46:24.920 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.699 Server also has ssh-dss host key, but we don't know it
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.699 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.699 ssh-rsa 1024 a8:d9:a6:9b:4e:2b:79:e4:bb:95:44:c3:30:19:67:f1
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.699 Verifying host key rsa2 0x23,0xca9a71a71ca07257 1e6ec7719211f02a 601cdebf1220f2cb 8d7bdd62175fb970 02331d38e4ad39be 09b3144f9033fd22 a94f9580d1626cba c2800b02a0775292 e532e9526ffb1d31 b9de89698278bf4d 8fdbde939db8715a 288df183bb145f5d 6490c0ef62a5142d e2b9c41b05d5caf7 e52ec1c0f8a3842e b14ce962b28ecda5  with fingerprint ssh-rsa 1024 a8:d9:a6:9b:4e:2b:79:e4:bb:95:44:c3:30:19:67:f1
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.745 Host key matches cached key
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.745 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.745 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.745 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.745 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
! 2018-03-09 15:46:25.745 Using username "service".
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.761 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,keyboard-interactive
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.761 Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.777 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server authentication", "Using keyboard-interactive authentication.", "Password: ")
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.777 Using stored password.
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.808 Prompt (keyboard interactive, "SSH server authentication", <no instructions>, <no prompt>)
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.808 Ignoring empty SSH server authentication request
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.808 Access granted
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.808 Opening session as main channel
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.808 Opened main channel
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.855 Primary command failed; attempting fallback
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.855 Started a shell/command
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.886 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-03-09 15:46:25.886 Using SFTP protocol.
```

Comment: Can you connect to the SFTP server with any SFTP client software with `ChrootDirectory` on?

Comment: Yes, for example WinSCP works without problems. I also tried using sshj library; may have same problems.

Comment: Show us WinSCP log file (with `ChrootDirectory` on).

Comment: Follwing link goes to [WinSCP log file: winscp-service@world-(dev)154623.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZYop0LlFf91clu2CyEF0q6NAo_tBf2AP/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message in WinSCP log means, that even WinSCP was not able to initiate "sftp" channel:

> . 2018-03-09 15:46:25.855 Primary command failed; attempting fallback
>   . 2018-03-09 15:46:25.855 Started a shell/command

WinSCP has a fallback mechanism, when "sftp" channel fails. It instead explicitly tries to run `sftp-server` binary in some common locations. But that's more or less a hack, which you should not try to reproduce in Java.

The primary problem is still that your SSH/SFTP configuration is broken.

And that's not a programming question. You better ask it at [Super User](https://superuser.com).

---

If you really need to reproduce the WinSCP hack, you need to modify JSch `ChannelSftp` to make `start` method do `RequestExec('/path/to/sftp-server')` instead of `RequestSftp` (or modify `RequestSftp` similarly).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After debugging jsch, you can see, that the server sends a `SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE`. I think, that this issue cannot be fixed in the library itself.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But as written above, I'm not able to change the server configuration in this case. So my application should solve this problem like WinSCP does. However,  I'll send these information, to our operators, too, to fix this.

Comment: Yes, this works. I copied original `ChannelSftp` class and updated the line to use `RequestExec(...)` instead of `ChannelSftp`. Now, I use this patched jsch library. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. I've added the solution to the answer. Though still, the right solution is to fix the server.